# проблема с прыжками в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Постоянно тестируя игру я обнаружил баг, что мой герой прыгал с разной силой прыжка.

часть кода:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private float forceJump;
public Transform[] groundPoint;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private bool jump;

private void HandleMovement()
{
    if (isGround && jump)
    {
        jump = false;
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, forceJump));
    }
}
private bool IsGround()
{
    //на земле или нет?
    if (rb.velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform point in groundPoint)
        {
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, 0.2f, whatIsGround);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    forceJump = 200.0f;

}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    HandleMovement();

    isGround = IsGround();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        jump = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: "с разной" - не темните, с возрастающей?

Comment: @Igor у него 2 силы прыжка. Один - очень слабый(почти не прыгает), другой - нормальный. Нормального больше всего. И самое главное, что это происходит рандомно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FixedUpdate вызывается от 0 до нескольких раз в кадр. То есть если вы нажали прыжок и fixedUpdate вызовется 3 раза за кадр. То у вас 3 раза addforce произойдет, прыжок будет длинее. Из-за этого и рандомная сила прыжка, не используйте Input в fixedUpdate никогда.